# Rewriting Javascript filter / forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach, javascript-objects

New to Javascript - I am attempting to rewrite forEach and filter to understand them. I'd like to be able to use filter to pass something like {"hello": 4, "world": 2, "hi": 1} and be able to filter based on the number.

Here's my forEach:

```
function myForEach(collection, callback) {

      if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
          callback(collection[i]);
        }
      }
      else {
        for (var key in collection) {
          callback(collection[key]);
        }
      }
    }
```

Here's filter:

```
function filterWithForEach (collection, predicate) {
  if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    var newArray = [];
    myForEach(collection, function (element) {
      if (predicate(element)) {
        newArray.push(element);
      }
    });
    return newArray;
  }
  else {
    var newCollection = {};
    myForEach(collection, function (element) {
      if (predicate(element)) {
        newCollection[element] = element; //here's where I think it's wrong
      }
    });
    return newCollection;
  }
}
```

I know the issue is with how I am assigning them because when I test it I get these outputs:

```
console.log(filterWithForEach([1,2,3,4,5], function(num) {
  return num > 2;
})); // works fine
console.log(filterWithForEach(aList, function(item) {
  return item > 3;
})); // provides {4: 4}..
```

Comment: Why are you collection everything in an object, in filter? `filter` is supposed to return an array.

Comment: Neither JavaScript's `forEach` nor `filter` does what you're doing in the case of an object that isn't array-like (nor do they limit themselves to arrays, just things that are array-*like*). If you want to know exactly what they do, the [spec is fairly clear](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18). The parts of your functions that handle arrays are reasonably on-target, although there are lots of details that are slightly different. Probably the most significant difference is that JavaScript's version doesn't call the callback for entries that don't exist.

Comment: Do you want just the value or you need to know key too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an object to be returned then this is the way it should be.

```
function myForEach(collection, callback) {

      if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
          callback(collection[i]);
        }
      }
      else {
        for (var key in collection) {
          callback(collection[key], key);
        }
      }
    }
```

Here's filter:

```
function filterWithForEach (collection, predicate) {
  if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    var newArray = [];
    myForEach(collection, function (element) {
      if (predicate(element)) {
        newArray.push(element);
      }
    });
    return newArray;
  }
  else {
    var newCollection = {};
    myForEach(collection, function (element,key) {
      if (predicate(element)) {
        newCollection[key] = element;           }
    });
    return newCollection;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Jessica: Note that neither of these behaves like JavaScript's `forEach` / `filter`. If the point is to understand those, writing something that behaves markedly differently makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know what they do, [the spec is fairly clear](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) and can pretty reasonably be turned into JavaScript code (in fact, that's been [done on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill)).

Some differences between yours and JavaScript's:

1. JavaScript's `forEach` and `filter` **don't** use `for-in`, which is the fundamental difference between yours and JavaScript's. They just work with the object and array indexes, expecting the object to be a *array-like* (e.g., have a `length` and properties with keys like `"0"`, `"1"`, and so on [and yes, all keys are strings, even the keys in standard arrays, which aren't really arrays at all).
2. JavaScript's version doesn't call the callback for entries that don't exist (e.g., in the case of sparse arrays). To add that to yours, you'd add `hasOwnProperty(index)` at some stage.
3. JavaScript's version passes more arguments to the callbacks.
4. JavaScript's version lets you specify a value to use as `this` when calling the callbacks.
5. JavaScript's version grabs the length before starting, so if the collection is modified, the old length is used. Depending on where the changes are made, entries might be skipped.

So for instance, your take on `forEach` might look more like this:

```
function myForEach(collection, callback, thisArg) {
    var l = +collection.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (collection.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            callback.call(thisArg, collection[i], i, collection);
        }
    }
}
```

Again, that's ***not*** (remotely) an accurate implementation of the algorithm in the spec, just a slight modification to yours to address the specific points I raised above.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! So helpful to get information like this. I'm going to read more on point 4. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can creat a filter own method into the Array prototype function. If you are looking for a different approach you can use Iterators and a recursive fuction like this:

```
Array.prototype.megaFilter = function(cb) {
  const iterator = this[Symbol.iterator]();
  const iteration = iterator.next();
  const filteredArray = [];
  iterate(iteration);
  function iterate(iteration) {
    if (iteration.done) return iteration;
    if (cb(iteration.value)) filteredArray.push(iteration.value);
    const nextIteration = iterator.next(iteration.value);
    return iterate(nextIteration);
  }
  return filteredArray;
};

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

console.log(array.megaFilter(v => v % 2 === 0));
```

The gist for that is here, you are very welcome to give me feedback:
https://gist.github.com/jdtorregrosas/d69f67e8079f82fbc2a5904e76a8fb6c